# How to improve accuracy or extrapolate missing or bad GPS points

Tags: gps, tracking, software-recommendations, post-processing

Is there an easy to use freeware tool to postprocess my location data, in order to correct 
1) location errors (or improve accuracy not based on differential GPS correction) and 
2) deal with missing locations, based on ecological information?

e.g. spikes in the location data are indicative of location errors, as are large angles between 3 fixes at small step sizes

Brown hare location data is based on small GPS collar  (U-blox LEA4S), and has been measured every 6 minutes in an open , relatively flat enviroment, including acceleration data every minute for 35 days, 24hr a day

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  In order for us to attempt to answer this question I think we will need to ask you to use the edit button to provide us with a lot more detail as to the types of location data and ecological information that you have.

Comment: What kind of errors do you want to correct?

Comment: @Martijn I suggest you to change the question's title in something like _"Possible ways to post-processing GPS data: How to improve accuracy or extrapolate missing or bad GPS points?"_ or something like that. "post processing data" is more a tag than a question....However have a look to this [link](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CEAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.smfn.unisi.it%2Fsmfn_lauree%2Fview_matdid.php%3Fid%3D1956&ei=Fw4vUqblOeem4gTfsID4Cg&usg=AFQjCNFoELheGuAB_lb23OKPS-94NQ-mqw&sig2=YbdTmBoUoEXYPOldwuULgw&bvm=bv.51773540,d.bGE&cad=rja).

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not your data can be post-processed is determined by the receiver that was used to collect it.  Based on what seems to be the datasheet for the receiver on the collar you mentioned ([available here](https://www2.u-blox.com/images/downloads/Product_Docs/LEA-4x_Data_Sheet(GPS.G4-MS4-06143).pdf)) it does not, to my knowledge, seem capable of post-processing - at least in the sense that you would post-process a file from Terrasync or something similar.

However, depending on how the data was collected you may have some other options to sanitize your data a bit.  For example, if the HDOP or PDOP for each position was recorded you could filter out the ones that are outside a given tolerance limit, that would likely eliminate the worst offenders.  Similarly, you could use the number of satellites that the receiver was connected to at any given time as an ordinal measure of position quality.

Ecological considerations are outside of the realm of my expertise so I cannot speak to any options that may exist there.  If it were me, I'd start by trying to filter out the worst offenders in the position data.  At least then you know you're working relatively close to reality.

Good luck!